# What does (x^2) do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was writing some calculations involving exponents in Javascript and due to my habit of using carets in Microsoft Excel, I typed `x^2` in the code. It still gave me an answer but it wasn't what I wanted. What does `^` do in javascript?

```
alert(Math.pow(3,2)); //result is 9
alert(3^2);           //result is 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bitwise XOR. Use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) for exponents.

If you do 3^2 you are actually doing:

```
3 XOR 2
```

Computers use Binary so they see

```
11 XOR 10
```

Put that into a table:

```
11     1 ^ 0 = 1
10     1 ^ 1 = 0
--
01
```

In simple terms:

> XOR will take the two numbers in binary, and for the bit to be true, they must be different

#### [Here's a list of all operators like `^`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

---

[`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) takes a base and an exponent:

> `Math.pow(3, 2)` --> 3<sup>2</sup> --> 9
>
> `Math.pow(5, 6)` --> 5<sup>6</sup> --> 15,625
>
> `Math.pow(7, 3)` --> 7<sup>3</sup> --> 343

Answer (score 2):

In `x^2`, `^` is the bitwise XOR operator and not the exponentiation operator as you expected, for that use: `Math.pow(x, 2)`.